# Module CSS is not getting loaded in the project

Tags: css, reactjs, npm

I've developing a react module and I've a react project setup in order to demo the react module. Everything worked fine the the webpack config was set to use the following css loader.

```
{
    test: /\.(css|less)$/,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
}
```

Which loads the CSS in the module perfectly in the project when the module is imported and used. But when I use the following,

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: ['css-loader']
    })
}
```

The CSS is generated but is not getting loaded in the project. I'm new to react and O followed the following tutorial to get an understanding of a react project structure. What am I doing wrong here?

[tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/a-tale-of-webpack-4-and-how-to-finally-configure-it-in-the-right-way-4e94c8e7e5c1)

Comment: {
                test: /\.s?css$/,  // scss & css files
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
                
            },

try this one

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have extracted css from module using below plugin

```
plugins: [ 
    new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'style.css'})
]
```

And also linked this css in your `index.html`

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```